# Windows 7 how to monitor folders a program is trying to create

Tags: windows, compatibility

I'm trying to get Sony Artisan software to work on Windows 7 32-bit. They were made for Windows XP. I got the drivers installed, but when the program starts up it gives an error can't create directory. It doesn't indicate which directory.

It is of course in XP SP2 compatibility mode run as an administrator.

Experience has shown me that Windows 7's security restrictions give older programs some trouble. For instance it gives them 'temporary storage' that they 'think' is in old locations. I've already created a directory junction from its program files folder to one where I moved the actual files, so it isn't a program files directory permissions problem.

I've made it work before, years ago. I seem to remember the fix being to create the directory for it. I have googled for over an hour and can't find results. So it seems the logical next thing to do is watch what folder it tries to create.

Googling doesn't come up with any answers to that problem either.

Anyone have a suggestion? Thanks

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Some programs have multiple exe's they call on when the main program exe is launched, sometimes you can go into the programs folder and do the compatibility with administrator for all exe's the main program might use.